# Independent window and icon for a custom chromium-URL .dekstop

Tags: icons, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

Is it possible to set the open app indicator on the custom `.desktop` and not on the programme that opens such file?

For example: I created a `.desktop` file for WhatsApp Web as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=WhatsApp
Type=Application
Exec=chromium-browser --app=https://web.whatsapp.com
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/user/Immagini/Icon/WhatsApp.png
Comment=WhatsApp web
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Network;
```

and I added it to dash. Clicking on WhatsApp, a new Chromium window opens:

[image]

But I would like that WhatsApp has an independent icon so that when I click another time on the WhatsApp icon, I open the window already opened and not a new chromium window.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 with dash-to-dock gnome-extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

1. Open the link of the website you want to add to your Dock in your Chrome/Chromium browser.
2. Open top-right menu (`⋮`) > `More tools` > `Add to desktop...`
3. Type a *suitable* title and make sure to tick `Open as window`.
4. You'll notice a new icon on your desktop (or ~/Desktop folder), launch it, right-click the icon on your Dock and `Add to Favorites`.
5. Done.

You can remove the created icon from your Desktop if you want.

**Note:** This will add an entry for the added website in your *GNOME Applications launcher*. If you don't want that, you can hide it by adding `NoDisplay=true` to the end of the corresponding *.desktop* file in `~/.local/share/applications/`